# How to solve this Error in Blueprism. "Failed to find stage linked from stage 'Start'." In Process Studio

Tags: blueprism

I have created Pages in Object Studio and I published them. then I am accessed them in Process Studio. So when I connected them in the order, in Start and End Of Process Studio Main Page It is giving me above Error "Internal:Failed to find stage linked from stage 'Start'." I tried to connect all pages to the start but it is giving me same error for all pages .[1) Error in Process Stydio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po7ne.png)  [2) Launch Page in Object Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFJMq.png) [3) Published Page which is getting accessed in Process studio.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgXaB.png). 
Pages in Object Studio runs perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a link between start and End on initialize page in object?

Comment: ohh that was the mistake. Got solved.Thanks.I didnt link start and end in iniialzation stage.

Comment: Had the same wtf moment on the first training day. Error message is not helpful at all.